# Search through methods in a class PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I used to work in Eclipse and had this very neat hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) which is used to search through the methods within a class.

I mean, if you are in the editor viewing a source of a class, and if you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, a pop-up comes up with all the methods listed. The list will get filtered if you start typing in. If I type in `get`, I can see a list of getters..

This is very helpful. I moved to PHP and PhpStorm and I miss this feature here, or I do not know if PhpStorm has this.

Do you guys have any idea of such a key combo in PhpStorm?

Comment: In IntelliJ it's Ctrl+F12 so it should be the same in PhpStorm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have never used Eclipse .. so not 100% sure how that popup looks and works .. but here is the PhpStorm functionality:

**Navigate | File Structure** (<kbd>Ctrl + F12</kbd> using Default keymap)

[image]

Alternatively just use [Speed Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html) (just start typing) in actual Structure panel.

Comment: This is what i wanted. Thank you!